# Worklight Studio not invoking adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I was trying to import the WL sample project for Android native push. After reconfiguring the options, I've tried to invoked the adapter, but it failed - there was no procedure to select:

[image: no procedure to call!]

My environment is:

- eclipse: 4.4.1.20140925-1820
- worklight studio: 6.2.0.00-20141002

Comment: tutorial - "Push notification in native Android applications"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse Java EE "Kepler" SR2 (you're using Luna, but that does not matter) with Worklight Studio 6.2.0.01.20141027-1531 (but this too should not matter).

After right-click the adapter folder (adapters > PushAdapter), I see the following:

[image]

1. What do you mean by "configuring the options"?
2. You can try with either a fresh workspace or a new Eclipse instance. Must be an Eclipse error.

Comment: Well, the "configuring the options" is not relevant. It's just about configuring the GCM sender ID and keys and etcs. Thanks for you help. It must be due to the eclipse. I'll try another instance later

Answer (score 0):

> try the tutorials link mention below for **http worklight adapters** from sketch level.
>
> 1. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_ibm_worklight_http_adapters_with_rest_json_services7?lang=en
> 2. http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf